# Cauchy-Goursat and removable singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

1. Cauchy-Goursat theorem (version 1) says: If $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ open set, and $f : U \to \mathbb{C}$ holomorph, then $\int_{\partial T} f = 0 \ \forall T \subseteq U$
2. Cauchy-Goursat theorem (version 2) says: If $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ open set, $p \in U$ and $f : U \to \mathbb{C}$ continuous and holomorphic in $U - \{p \}$, then $\int_{\partial T} f = 0 \ \forall T \subseteq U$
3. A theorem of Riemann about removable singularities says:
   Let $p \in U$ be an isolated singularity.  If $\exists \lim_{z \to p} f(z) = L \in \mathbb{C}$ then $p$ is removable singularity, that means that if we define $f(p) = L$ then $f$ is holomorphic in $p$.

Doesn't 3. imply that in 2. $f$ is in fact holomorphic in all $U$ and so it is equivalent to 1.?

Is the reason why this is not a valid proof of 2.  that the proof of the 3. requires that holomorphic functions are analytic which in turn requires the Cauchy integral formula in convex sets which in turn requires 2.?

Comment: Yes, you are right on both.